# Linq select into objects containing collection type variables

Tags: .net, linq

Suppose I have a list of database records like this :

```
Warehouse   goods

A           apple

A           orange

B           apple

B           banana
```

Is it possible using linq to select into two objects say object A and object B each contains a collection of its goods?

Comment: Does `.GroupBy(r=>r.Warehouse)` work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Linq is more about querying and less about what you do with the results of the query. That's why you see methods like `Select` and `Where` but not `Add` or `Update`.

You can take the results of a query and add them into two separate collections, or you can iterate over items in a collection and perform more than one action on them, like inspecting them and adding them to one or more collections.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace SO36322037
{
    class Record
    {
        public string Warehouse { get; set; }
        public string Goods { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {

        static void Main()
        {
            var list = new List<Record>
            {
                new Record {Warehouse = "A", Goods = "apple"},
                new Record {Warehouse = "A", Goods = "orange"},
                new Record {Warehouse = "B", Goods = "apple"},
                new Record {Warehouse = "B", Goods = "banana"},
            };

            var result = list.GroupBy(l => l.Warehouse, l => l.Goods).ToList();
            foreach (var warehouse in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Warehouse: {warehouse.Key}");
                foreach (var goods in warehouse)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"\tGoods: {goods}");
                }
            }

            // This is your object A
            var A = result.Single(x => x.Key == "A").ToList();

            // This is your object B
            var B = result.Single(x => x.Key == "B").ToList();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can do something like that using 'group by'

```
var items = new List<Record>
        {
            new Record {Warehouse = "A", Goods = "apple"},
            new Record {Warehouse = "A", Goods = "orange"},
            new Record {Warehouse = "B", Goods = "apple"},
            new Record {Warehouse = "B", Goods = "banana"},
        };
var warehouses = from item in items
                 group item.Goods by item.Warehouse
```

you can the iterate over the result like this

```
foreach(var warehouse in warehouses){
    //...
    foreach(var item in warehouse){
         //...
    }
}
```